# godbolt fails to link when including windows.h on MSVC?

Tags: c++

*Now Im fully aware this may not be the **correct** site to post this question, but Im a bit lost where else to post it.*

Using the [*godbolt.org* compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/bauHxE), has shown to be great little tool for many things (including on this site).

However, it seems linking on windows platform isn't very well 'supported' when including windows headers (or am I missing something). Compilation works just fine, but linking seems to fail. (and there seem to be no option in the library list)

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN 
#include <windows.h>

int main (void)
{
     return 0;
}
```

Yields the link error:

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'LIBCMT.lib'
```

Anyone know what's the reason for this ? (or if theres hack/workaround ?)

It compiles fine, but the little './a.out' is disabled on the compiler pane (as isn't the case for `gcc`). Also the executor (the pane to the right) works seemingly fine - just not when including and thus linking with any windows headers.

**What is a '*shareable*' way to get code executed with windows headers linked, if there is one ? (eg. for use on this site)**

Comment: This has an [issue here](https://github.com/mattgodbolt/compiler-explorer/issues/441). Godbolt's MSVC actually doesn't run on windows, but on Wine. See also [this issue](https://github.com/mattgodbolt/compiler-explorer/issues/1502).

Comment: Perhaps use another site that can run windows programs, such as [rextester](https://rextester.com/QUROH18364)?

Comment: @nada The bug you link seems not to be the issue here. That is about a compile error when including windows.h

Comment: @darune See 2nd link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known issue with the software ([#1502](https://github.com/mattgodbolt/compiler-explorer/issues/1502)).

Summary:

> Execution is not supported on any MSVC compiler currently.
>   The wine compilers run on our infrastructure, but are not able to produce a binary.
>   The non-wine compilers run on microsoft's infrastructure and we have no control over them.
>
> I believe it is a bug that these compilers even show up in the dropdown on the execution only pane.

Any further engagement about this issue should take place on that bug tracker.